# ThreadPoolExecutor internals

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm using `concurrent.futures`' class `ThreadPoolExecutor` to do stress testing on a webservice.

As far as I can understand, the `max_workers` constructor parameters tell the executor what's the maximum number of threads that will be in the pool. Anyway, is there any guarantee that that's the number that will be effectively used, or it could be lesser (for example, due to some hardware limitation) than that?

If so, is there a way to know how many worker threads will be effectively instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the doc

```
    Args:
        max_workers: The maximum number of threads that can be used to
            execute the given calls.
```

from the code, _adjust_thread_count(), seems the new thread is created on demand and limited by max_workers.

```
    if len(self._threads) < self._max_workers:
        t = threading.Thread(target=_worker,
                             args=(weakref.ref(self, weakref_cb),
                                   self._work_queue))
```

also seems `len(self._threads)` is for the effectively instantiated.

Comment: Indeed, by looking at ProcessExplorer's Threads panel it seems that the max_workers is always honored. Thank you :)